# Limit scrollView range after Button click in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a scrollview with block of information. An example of the function i am looking for is. ..
Button A
Button B
Button C
ScrollView - has a height of 3000, width 320 (portrait layout in iOS)

button A i set the cgPointMake
[scrollViewSettings setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0)];

button B i set the cgPointMake
[scrollViewSettings setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,1000)];

button C i set the cgPointMake
[scrollViewSettings setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,2000)];

I do not have any code beyond this in regards to setting scroll limits or scroll range.
what i need is

Button A to have a scroll height range from y=0 to y=1000 so the user cannot scroll to see data where button B or C will take them.

Button B to have a scroll height range from y=1000 to y=2000 so the user cannot scroll up or down to see data where button A or C will take them.

Button C to have a scroll height range from y=1000 to y=2000 so the user cannot scroll up to see data where button A or B will take them.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the code i used for each scrollview

```
scrollViewMain.frame = CGRectMake(0, 54, 320,426); /*set the viewable frame of the scroll view*/
[scrollViewMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1708)]; /*set the content size of the scroll view*/

scrollViewSettings.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,426); /*set the viewable frame of the scroll view*/
[scrollViewSettings setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,650)]; /*set the content size of the scroll view*/

scrollViewBMI.frame = CGRectMake(0, 426, 320,426); /*set the viewable frame of the scroll view*/
[scrollViewBMI setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,570)]; /*set the content size of the scroll view*/

scrollViewBFC.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1278, 320,426); /*set the viewable frame of the scroll view*/
[scrollViewBFC setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,568)]; /*set the content size of the scroll view*/

ViewBMR.frame = CGRectMake(0, 852, 320,426); /*set the viewable frame of the view*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use 3 differents UIView and display the view you want in the scrollview.

Ex :

Create a first view that contains the same UI than your range (0 to 1000)
Create a second view that contains the same UI than the second  range (1000 to 2000)
etc...

And add the view you need when button A or B or C is pressed (removing the previous view).

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: My example has 3 views same size which is not true to what i need. what if the content area for each is a different size.

Comment: button A i set the cgPointMake [scrollViewSettings setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0)];

button B i set the cgPointMake [scrollViewSettings setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,800)];

button C i set the cgPointMake [scrollViewSettings setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,800)];

Comment: I took what you said and applied it. I set 3 scrollviews inside the main scrollview. each CGRect(320,480) but I set the true height in code.